# Firebase .onCall Cloud Function not being called from within Swift Xcode Project

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have added an iOS app to a firebase project and for some reason the function doesn't get called when I call it from iOS. The connection to Firebase seems to be fine as I can run queries on the Firebase database from within the swift project but when I run the swift cloud function it seems to bypass the code.

Below is the test cloud function I have created just to investigate this:

```
  exports.testFunction = functions.https.onCall((data,context) => {
      console.log("hi the test function worked");
      return "hi the test function worked";
  })
```

And this is the swift code I am using to call the function,

```
lazy var functions = Functions.functions()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    functions.httpsCallable("testFunction").call("Hi", completion: {(result,error) in
        if let error = error{
            print("An error occurred while calling the test function: \(error)" )
        }
        print("Results from test cloud function: \(result)")
    })

    return true
}
```

I've tried updating cocoa pods and creating new projects but nothing has seemed to work. There is nothing being returned to my iOS project or being logged in the firebase console. There are no errors thrown, does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing such a strange occurrence to happen? Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution, i am stuck

Comment: @yusuftezel No I filed a bug report with firebase but somehow it resolved itself. It appeared as though there was some kind of glitch or crash from firebase because it just resumed automatically  10 hours later without changing a single line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered just the same problem yesterday.  The symptom I saw is the exactly the same as yours.  I've managed to make it work by downgrading my Firebase pod versions, since I've used cloud functions before and they work.

My pod versions for Firebase/Core, Firebase/Functions, Firebase/Messaging were all 5.15.0 and they did not work.

I changed them to 5.7.0 and now they are working as expected.

I have not tried the versions in between.

**Update:
The problem seems to be fixed in version 5.18.0 that came out today.**

Comment: It is a very strange occurrence the problem just resolved itself for me within a day without changing a single line of code. I've been noticing throughout my use of firebase overall these types of incidences occurring more frequently without any kind of notice. Hopefully the more bug reports we file the sooner they will find whatever is causing this to occur.

Comment: Yeah after reading your comment I waited overnight but the problem didn't go away hence I opted to the answer I wrote.  Google is pretty good about fixing problems, so let's hope that they will.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an async method, you are exiting your method block before the network request is finished. This may cause the connection to the server to close before you get a request back.

Personally I wouldn't make any network requests in appDelegate, but in your first viewController viewDidLoad to test anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried moving the function as you suggested to the `viewDidLoad()` of the first `ViewController` called and still nothing has occurred. I suspect the problem may have something to do with Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue, and testing all mentioned scenarios but after a long timeout, the error was always the same.

Switching network connection from "USB-MAC-PHONE shared", to Phone 4G. And the call is successful.

I have not time to test further at the moment, just noticed that issue also replicates on simulators.